# Problema basico en Python

Tags: python

tengo un problema con una operacion que me registra errores constantemente y no tengo idea del porque. Tengo que crear un algoritmo que me de a elegir entre 3 opciones asignada con numero (1, opcion 1, 2, opcion 2, 0 salir) , opcion 1,factorizar, opcion 2, buscar el area del circulo, opcion 3 terminar el algoritmo. Continuamente me da errores por la funcion INT y no puedo resolverlo (disculpen, soy nuevo en esto). Agradeceria su ayuda, hasta entonces tengo esto:

[image: Ejercicio_Python]

Gracias de antemano

Comment: ¿te da error o bien te vuelve a pedir el número? No es lo mismo. Sospecho que te ocurre lo segundo, debido a la comparación `valor1 = 0 or 1 or 2` que no solo no hace lo que supones (tendría que ser `valor1 == 0 or valor1 == 1 or valor1 == 2`), sino que ni siquiera se evalúa en un condicional, Ah, y no debe incluirse el código como imagen en la pregunta, sino como texto dentro de un bloque delimitado por ```

Comment: Es `int(input())`, no `input(int())`.

Comment: La expresión `valor1 = 0 or 1 or 2` siempre hará que `valor1` sea `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola Cosme Fulanito espero que te encuentres muy bien, en las línea 15 y  19 de tu código tienes input(int()) y lo correcto es int(input()) como lo tienes en la línea 7. También vi que si la entrada fuera 0 te causaría error la línea 22 porque nunca fue declarada la variable “resultado”. En la línea 20 el área de circulo es pi*(radio ** 2) no radio*(pi ** 2), para elevar un numero exponencialmente se utiliza el ** en vez de ^. En la línea 16 estas usando la entrada numérica como si fuera una función y la función de factorizar como si fuera un número, solo sería cambiar el orden de esos por ejemplo resultado = factorizar(numerof). En la línea 12 tienes valor1 = 0 or 1 or 2, tu intención creo que era hacer que la entrada estuviera dentro del rango, en el ejemplo que te dejo ahí viene una forma fácil para ver si la opción de entrada esta fuera del rango que la pregunte otra vez.

Te dejo un código de ejemplo:

```
from math import factorial, pi

print("Calcular\n1. Factorizar\n2. Area de un circulo\n3. Salir")
while True:
    try:
        opcionMenu = int(input("Escribe aqui: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("Debe ingrear un numero entero")
        continue
    if opcionMenu < 1 or opcionMenu > 3:
        print("Valor fuera de rango")
    else:
        break

if opcionMenu == 1:
    factorizar = int(input("Ingrese el numero a factorizar: "))
    print(f'La factorizacion es: {factorial(factorizar)}')
elif opcionMenu == 2:
    radio = int(input("Ingresa el radio del circulo: "))
    print(f'El area es: {pi * (radio**2)}')
```

Espero que te sea de utilidad, con el tiempo iras perfeccionando tus habilidades, cualquier cosa aquí estamos al pendiente.
Saludos.

Comment: Gracias amigo, en el tiempo que paso desde que publique pude resolver el algoritmo pero tu solución es incluso mas limpia, te lo agradezco mucho.